# Override ActiveRecord dynamic finders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a external library that depends on `find_by_id`, but my primary key is `uuid`. The `id` column doesn't exist.

Is there a way to have `Model.find_by_id` aliased to `Model.find_by_uuid`, or even just `Model.find`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, dynamic `find_by` methods are out of favor and `Model.find_by(uuid: '123')` are preferred.

But in your case, it sounds like you could override the primary key like so.

```
class Model
  self.primary_key = 'uuid'
end
```

This would allow you to do `Model.find('1234-1234-1234-1234')`

I still don't think this will work for `find_by_id`, since that is specifying the column name on which to look. If you are really dependent on this external library, you could override `find_by_id`

```
class Model
  def self.find_by_id(id)
    find_by uuid: id
  end
end
```

Comment: Yeah, upstream has a hack that doesn't work. And they won't want to switch. https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery/issues/634

Answer (score 0):

There really is no need to get fancy and modify or override anything

```
Model.find_by (uuid: client_id)
```

or

```
Model.where(uuid: client_id).take
```

Will work for your querying needs. [Active record querying documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

Comment: Nope! can't. upstream library. it does a `find_by_id` specifically. Maintainer doesn't think it's appropriate to change it.

Comment: ahh, well that would be a problem.  @evanbikes answer should fit your needs well. Good luck.